# wsdl with conflicting xsd imports

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws, wsimport

I tried to find a solution for some time to the following problem. I have a wsdl file containing several (6) xsd imports. I cannot change these xsd's because they are external to my project. There are 4 definitions all together which are slightly defined different in 2 of these schemas. I was attempting to translate each 'conflicting' xsd schema to it's own package. I tried following bindings, but it did not do the job:

testbindings.jaxb:

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">
    <bindings schemaLocation="a.xsd">
         <schemaBindings>
               <package name="org.wsi.a" />
         </schemaBindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

using: `wsimport -p org.wsi -b testbindings.jaxb  broker.wsdl`

All classes are generated in `org.wsi` and no classes in `org.wsi.a`. Without the -p switch all xsd  are generated in their own default package. But could not tell wsimport to use specific packages for each xsd. At this moment I use following binding file, which is probably incorrect, but for which the wsimport doesn't complain:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"              xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">

<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="broker.wsdl" node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema">

    <jaxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" node="//xs:schema/xs:import[@namespace='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2']">>
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="org.broker.wsi.b_2"/>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

    <jaxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" node="//xs:schema/xs:import[@namespace='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1']">>
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="org.broker.wsi.t_1"/>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxws:bindings>
```

In packages org.broker.wsi.b_2 and org.broker.wsi.t_1, no files are generated.

I used bindings as specified in: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv/data_types.html#wp227713  but probably incorrect.

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did you copy-paste everything correctly? `'<'schemaLocation="b-2.xsd" node="/xsd:schema"'>'` seems fishy.

Comment: How do you import the schemas? Can you paste (an anonimized version of) your schema imports? I'm referring to the <wsdl:types><xsd:schema ... targetnamespace="THIS IS IT"></xsd:schema></wsdl:types> part of the wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of setting up the correct package names for the wsdl, the internal xsd and the external xsd's is described in question/answer:

- [wsimport - how to generate service endpoint classes and JAXB classes in separate projects/folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211668/wsimport-how-to-generate-service-endpoint-classes-and-jaxb-classes-in-seperate), posted by:
  [dma-k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267197/dma-k)

int-bindings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jaxws:bindings version="2.0"
                xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"                 
            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
            xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
            wsdlLocation="broker.wsdl">

<jaxws:package name="org.broker.wsi" />

<jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:schema">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="org.broker.wsi.al"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

The external-bindings file (abbreviated):

```
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2.xsd" node="//xsd:schema">
            <jaxb:schemaBindings>
                 <jaxb:package name="org.broker.wsi.oasis.b2"/>
            </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```